# Difference between REALM,SQLITE,FCM database

Tags: android

#### Difference between REALM,SQLITE,FCM database

What is the main Difference between REALM,SQLITE,FCM database.Why i am prefer this database and explain internal working process? any body can suggest me.

Comment: I think you need to understand each database features instead of finding difference or comparison with each other and choose appropriate database which is more suitable for your requirement.

Comment: yes i want to know internal working process feature robustness security etc

Answer (score 4):

REALM,SQLITE,FCM database are all databases use to store your app data

**SQLite** - SQLite is a opensource SQL database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android comes in with built in SQLite database implementation. SQLite supports all the relational database features.

**Realm** - Realm is a mobile database and a replacement for SQLite. Realm is not using SQLite as it’s engine. Instead it has own C++ core and aims to provide a mobile-first alternative to SQLite. Realm store data in a universal, table-based format by a C++ core. This is what allows Realm to allow data access from multiple languages as well as a range of ad hoc queries.

Below are the advantages of Realm over SQLite:
1. faster than SQLite (up to 10x speed up over raw SQLite for normal operations)
2. easy to use
3. object conversion handled for you
4. convenient for creating and storing data on the fly

**FCM database** - The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client. FCM does not create its own database on the device but it has an offline feature that lets developers to store any data locally when the device is not connected to internet. Normally REST/SOAP API is created to access or udpdate data in a centralized database. FCM database can help you eliminating the creation of webservice as you can create your database directly on FCM and access it using their SDK.

Comment: I know this differece can you explain internal working differece like robustness ,security etc